# Issue while creating costum module in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I am trying to create new custom module in drupal 8 . I got given below logs . and system is not responding now . I am unable to logged in in drupal 8 site .

Log is given below :- 
[Mon May 01 19:15:28.999581 2017] [:error] [pid 1892:tid 1660] [client ::1:60090] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "first_module.content" does not exist." at D:\PHP server\xampp-win32-5.6.30-0-VC11\xampp\htdocs\drupal_8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php line 187

Answer (score 0):

Which files have you created for custom module. Drupal 8 requires only 1 file as a start.

```
custom_module.info.yml

name: Custom module name
description: 'Module Description'
type: module
core: 8.x
package: Custom
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a route "first_module.content" in your code which is not available.

Make sure the route exist in your first_module.routing.yml and you have cleared your cache.

If the website is not responding and you are not able to clear cache, go to your database and TRUNCATE all the tables with prefix 'cache_'.